# Unable to use equ.traineddata for tesseract (throes error) but hin,ben,eng works well

Tags: python-3.x, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I have my `tesseract` installed at `/usr/share/tesseract-ocr/` and is working fine wit hte `tessdata` directory at `/usr/share/tesseract-ocr/4.0/tessdata`. Because the `equ.traineddata` is not given with the original data, I have downoaded it from the officil documentation at managed to paste it at the `/usr/share/tesseract-ocr/4.0/tessdata/equ.traineddata`. Aong with it, I pasted `hin,ben` and a few more files too. When I use `--l eng+hin+ben` it works fine but with the `equ` it throws error. I used `pytesseract` too with a few configs such as:

```
# making a copy of tessdata dir in the home
cli_config = '--oem 1 --psm 12 --tessdata-dir ~/tessdata/ -l eng+equ+ben+hin'
ocr.image_to_string(image=img_path,config=cli_config)
```

and also

```
cli_config = '--oem 1 --psm 12` # tessdata is at default location too
ocr.image_to_string(image=img_path,config=cli_config,lang='eng+equ+hin+ben`)
```

but it keeps throwing me error **ONLY FOR** `equ` like:

```
TesseractError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-8529ae8e51e8> in <module>
----> 1 ocr.image_to_string(image=img_path,config=cli_config,lang='equ')

~/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py in image_to_string(image, lang, config, nice, output_type, timeout)
    356         Output.DICT: lambda: {'text': run_and_get_output(*args)},
    357         Output.STRING: lambda: run_and_get_output(*args),
--> 358     }[output_type]()
    359 
    360 

~/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py in <lambda>()
    355         Output.BYTES: lambda: run_and_get_output(*(args + [True])),
    356         Output.DICT: lambda: {'text': run_and_get_output(*args)},
--> 357         Output.STRING: lambda: run_and_get_output(*args),
    358     }[output_type]()
    359 

~/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py in run_and_get_output(image, extension, lang, config, nice, timeout, return_bytes)
    264         }
    265 
--> 266         run_tesseract(**kwargs)
    267         filename = kwargs['output_filename_base'] + extsep + extension
    268         with open(filename, 'rb') as output_file:

~/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py in run_tesseract(input_filename, output_filename_base, extension, lang, config, nice, timeout)
    240     with timeout_manager(proc, timeout) as error_string:
    241         if proc.returncode:
--> 242             raise TesseractError(proc.returncode, get_errors(error_string))
    243 
    244 

TesseractError: (1, 'Error opening data file /home/deshwal/anaconda3/envs/py36/share/tessdata/equ.traineddata Please make sure the TESSDATA_PREFIX environment variable is set to your "tessdata" directory. Failed loading language \'equ\' Tesseract couldn\'t load any languages! Could not initialize tesseract.')
```

What could be the reason for this? How can use the `equ.traineddata` ?

Answer (score 1):

`equ` is legacy language data. Thus, you'd need to use the appropriate `oem` value. Try `tesseract --help-extra` command to show usage.

Comment: Thanks. Got it. But the thing is that The actual problem was that my `equ` was not present at `/home/deshwal/anaconda3/envs/py36/share/tessdata/`. Somehow, it is not looking at the original directory but the `conda` one